# Article: Author information when occupation has changed

Tags: publications, citations, authorship, citation-style

I'm currently the main author of a paper. The work was performed when I was working at university X. However, I will start at a new university Y in one month, and the conference I'm presenting the work at is in two months. So, while presenting the paper I will be working at university Y (but the work was performed during my time at university X).

My question is the following, how would you present the author information:

A)

Both universities in the main information.

```
First name, Lastname (1, 2)  

(1) University X 
email@university_X.com  

(2) University Y 
email@university_Y.com
```

B)

Name and previous affiliation (where the work was completed) as the main information and the current affiliation in a footnote.

```
First name, Lastname 
(Footnote: 'Currently working at University Y, email@university_Y.com')  
University X 
email@university_X.com
```

or C)

Name and current affiliation as the main information and the previous affiliation (where the work was completed) in a footnote.

```
First name, Lastname 
(Footnote: 'Work completed at University X, email@university_X.com')  
University Y, 
email@university_Y.com
```

Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This may be specific to journal, research area, whatnot. However, in a recent edition of Applied Physics Letters one finds in the author list:

[image]

The "2" corresponds to an institute in the affiliations list (other authors have other affiliations) where the author was at during the work.

The "a)" links to:

[image]

Followed by the new address for that person.

Other uses for footnotes include email addresses and apportioning credit.

This is how it was done some 25 years ago when I last changed institutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is only from my personal standpoint, what I would like to read in the paper. Your final choice (C) seems best, as people (i.e. *me*) will want to use any email address to contact you *now* and the old one may become obsolete. So, in current papers your contact information should be current.

But I would also expand a bit on your footnote as the previous employer likely has an interest in your paper and has contributed some resources to it, even if indirectly. The note should thank them for support that made the work possible. You don't even need an email address unless you have some guarantee that mail will be forwarded to you in the future.

However, this also assumes that the work wasn't done under any sort of contract that specifies attribution and such.